# How to make sure the program is running for long time and not shut down by the system?

Tags: android

To be more specific, in my app there are recorder and accelerometer running in 2 services to record sleep cycle, and I need to make sure these 2 components stay up all night long (8 hours for example), how do I make sure they will not be killed or shut by the android system itself?
Although I doubt it will, because they are not memory/CPU intensive anyway, but just in case if this really happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way for you to be able to do this.

Instead, you could try uninstalling everything else on the device, and force stopping everything that can't be removed. Also, put the device in airplane mode. Doing these three should be a good way to ensure that your device doesn't run short on resources, as it won't be doing much else.

However, logging data from the accelerometer for 8 hours will be *very* battery intensive, and your battery is likely to run out before 8 hours are up.

Answer (score 0):

As your service shut downs, this will call the ondestroy method. So do the work inside the ondestroy method to restart your service.

Comment: However, if the system is low on resources it'll just keep killing the service everytime it starts. Therefore, his best bet would be to try to make sure that the system doesn't run low on resources to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can set alarm manager for specific time let say every  30 mins which trigger the device to and then you check if your desire service is running or not